# C# - Powershell AddPSSnapin Causes errors

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, x86-64, system.management

So, I import the `System.Management.Automation` dll and I'm trying to run a `New-Mailbox` command with params

so I use:

```
RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException psEx = null;
config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out psEx);
```

That's all fine and dandy... but when I go to run the application I get the following:
`Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 because of the following error: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Globals' threw an exception.`

So, I did some research online and found that I need to change from `Any CPU` to `x86` as the platform target.

However, when I do that I get a `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` error

I am almost positive that I have to run it as a 32 bit process so that it can use the snapin (which from other reading seems to be what the snapin is running under)

I did change the app pool to `Enable 32-bit Applications` to `True`. Which is when I get the error.

I've read other posts... but, I'm not sure how to get past this `Service unavailable` thing.

I've tried using a x64 build and get `Could not load file or assembly 'EmailAdminWeb2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: Did you install exchange management shell 2010?

Comment: Yes. I can actually run any and all scripts from powershell by running `add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use this at all:

```
config.AddPSSnapIn("your snapin here", out psEx);
```

instead.... just use a connection as follows:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://yourdomainhere/Powershell/Microsoft.Exchange"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", PsCreds);
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

Now run your commands and you're good to go.

Quick notes:

- Make sure you're app is targeting `x64` not `Any CPU` or `x86`
- If you're using .net 4.5 (or 4) make sure you're app pools are set properly (v4.0 not v2.0) and that you have `Enable 32bit apps` set to false